# I am trying to link a list to a sharepoint website using js, the list is Utilities Contract and I want to bring back specific columns from that list

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint

I am trying to link a list to a sharepoint website using javascript, the list is called 'Utilities Contract' and  I want to bring back specific columns from that list. This is the code I have so far.

```js
function retrieveSpecificListProperties(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

    clientContext.load(collList, 'Include(Title, Id)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listInfo = '';
    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + 
            ' ID: ' + oList.get_id().toString() + '\n';
    }
    alert(listInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below mentioned code to get that data:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();

var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Utilities Contract');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync( 
    function(){
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

            var itemTitle = oListItem.get_item('Title');

            var itemId = oListItem.get_id();
    },
    function(sender, args){
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
});
```

More exhaustive samples - [How to: Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185007(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am just able to view the javascript code whats the best way of incorporating it into the sharepoint website.

Comment: you can use a content editor webpart or script editor webpart and just add this snippet into it

Comment: I want to be able to put it into a html table myself. Just good practice for myself really. Do you know how too?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, use the fetched data from the above code and bind that data into your html table. The HTML can reside in a Content editor or Script editor webpart. Easy way to bind data would be to use jQuery. Could you please mark it as answer if it helped solve your issue? Thanks !